# Is there any GUI tools for flash feathers?

Tags: flash-builder, flash-cs6

I found "feathers" that UIComponent library in FP11.
    http://feathersui.com/

but In this library's tutorial, there is only usage by coding and no any GUI tools.

Is there anyone who know GUI tools for feathers?

Please let me know :)

thanks.

Additionally..

I'm just wondering If there isn't any good GUI tools, what is the pros or strengths of the feathers?
hum........

Comment: not a good question for SO but id still like to know the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no GUI editor available.

Here's the ticket: https://github.com/joshtynjala/feathers/issues/309

You can try out [fluid-feathers](https://github.com/Hyzhak/fluid-feathers) for declarative-like UI description, though.